# How can I apply Month function inside a criteria interval in the SUMIFS excel function?

Tags: excel, function, formula, criteria, sumifs

I'm using excel to do budgeting and I have this situation:
I have a grid with expense categories as rows and months as columns and I write expenses in the right list, this is an example:

[image]

Using a column for the month I can easily automatically do the sum for month inside the grid.
Every cell of the grid has this formula:

```
=SOMMA.PIÙ.SE($G$2:$G$50;$F$2:$F$50;$A2;$I$2:$I$50;MESE(DATA.VALORE(B$1&"1")))
```

In english it must be something like this (I'm italian):

```
=SUMIFS($G$2:$G$50,$F$2:$F$50,$A2,$I$2:$I$50,MONTH(DATEVALUE(B$1&"1")))
```

This works, but I would like to remove the I column and automatically take the month values of the dates in the criteria interval, is it possible?

I've tried also using MAP function this way:

```
=SUMIFS($G$2:$G$50,$F$2:$F$50,$A2,MAP($H$2:$H$50,LAMBDA(a,MONTH(a))),MONTH(DATEVALUE(B$1&"1")))
```

But neither this way it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you will need to include an explicit reference to the year, e.g.:

`=LET(ξ,DATEVALUE(B$1&23),SUMIFS($G$2:$G$50,$F$2:$F$50,$A2,$H$2:$H$50,">="&ξ,$H$2:$H$50,"<"&EDATE(ξ,1)))`

If 2023 is not the appropriate year, replace the 23 in the part

`DATEVALUE(B$1&23)`

as required.

Comment: Thank you so much, the year was not the real problem, because you can obtain the correct month number even putting "1" after the month name inside Datevalue(), what makes difference is the Let() function that I didn't know. Nice and elegant, ChatGpt didn't win yet :)

Comment: @Kronos24 Yes, but you're not referencing column I anymore, so inclusion of the year is in fact necessary.